# Copiar mensagens SMS recebidas pelo iPhone

Tags: app, iphone, sms

Estou precisando saber se há um meio de ter acesso as mensagens de SMS já recebidas pelo iPhone. Se existe algo parecido como a ter acesso aos contatos.

Não encontrei nada falando se é possível ou não. Mas não é para app de furto não. É uma ideia que tive para um novo app.

obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como pode ser visto [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4728576/1606920), não é possível interceptar/ler SMS devido questões de privacidade, pelo menos em uma amostra que não tenha passado pelo processo de jailbreak.
A única coisa que a sua app pode fazer relacionado a SMS, segundo a proposta da Apple, é enviar SMSs.